# Installing Docker with sudo

Tags: docker, openshift

I am trying to set up a Discourse forum on OpenShift. When I try to install docker,

```
$> wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/ | sh
Error: this installer needs the ability to run commands as root.
We are unable to find either "sudo" or "su" available to make this happen.
$> sudo wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/ | sh
bash: usr/bin/sudo: permission denied.
$> su wget -qO- https://get.docker.io/ | sh
bash: /bin/sudo: permission denied.
```

Comment: first `sudo su` to be root, then the first command will do

Comment: Do you have root access ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have root access on OpenShift as a web dev. You also do not need docker nor will it work on the current version of OpenShift.

You should use this instead:

https://github.com/liquidautumn/discourse-quickstart/tree/master/.openshift