# Openshift Discourse liquidautumn not working

Tags: github, openshift

I had tried deploying discourse on openshift through serveral ways but all failed and i got this thread trustable  [Installing Docker with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29447524/installing-docker-with-sudo)

But this one too is giving me this error while creating app

[image]

I had also tried deploying discourse using liquidautumn through commandline, i had changed the vestalversions repo to another working one, but there are still many issues while deploying.

Later i tried this repo 
https://github.com/NeilBryant/discourse-quickstart-neb

But unfortunately went through version issues,

All these repo are updated at least 2 years ago

Could some one refer me any working repo or article to easily deploy discourse over openshift, or if any of these repo contributors went through this question, please figure out what's wrong with the repo code.

It's causing me days of work in vain

Comment: Why uppercase? Is anybody dying?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nick.  Could you please refer any other working ways to deploy discourse over openshift ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have sudo privs on OpenShift Online.

That image is to small to read the error, can you use pastebin or something?

You should try posting an issue on the git repository for that quickstart/cartridge and ask the maintainer about it. (That would probably be the best way to get help on it)

Comment: Thanks moleculartear, I had posted an issue on the github repository and waiting for their reply. Could you please refer any other working ways to deploy discourse over openshift

Answer (score 0):

The two repos are too old, but if you are always interested I just pushed a repo with the last version of discourse (1.4.3).
The repo: https://github.com/koko-ng/discourse-openshift-quickstart
The little installation guide: https://github.com/koko-ng/discourse-openshift-quickstart/wiki/Installation

If you are experiencing any trouble during the installation, just open an issue on GitHub.